# Flask: 2FA if statement keeps failing potentially due to different vaiable types?

Tags: python, html, flask, two-factor-authentication

I have tried to make my own 2FA code using flask-email
I generate a 6 digit OTP here:

```python
def OTP(length):
    printable = '0123456789'
    printable = list(printable)
    random.shuffle(printable)
    OTP = random.choices(printable, k=length)
    OTP = ''.join(OTP)
    return OTP
```

then i send an email with OTP here and return the OTP so i can use later

```python
def email():
    email = session['email']
    password = OTP(6)
    msg = Message('Business Account 2FA Password', sender='sholto@nea.com', recipients=[email])
    msg.body = ('Hi ' + email + ' Please use this OTP (one time password) to access your business account: \n' + password)
    mail.send(msg)
    return password
```

Here i use OTP = email() to send the email and get the value of the password then the code checks if the OTP the user enters matches the on stored in OTP variable.

```html
@app.route('/Authentication', methods = ['POST','GET'])
def Authentication():
    OTP = email()
    if request.method=='POST':
        pass1=request.form.get('password1')
        if pass1==OTP:
            flash('business account login successful')
            session['compcode']=compcode
            session['uniquepass']=uniquepass
            return redirect(url_for('user'))
        else:
            flash('Incorrect Password')
            return redirect(url_for('logout'))
    return render_template('2FA.html')
```

No matter how many times i enter the OTP and enter the correct OTP the if statement always falls through to the else clause. grrr please help p.s(I think the problem  may be that i am comparing two different data types but after trying to manipulate the variables im still lost!)
HTML template code below

```html
{%extends 'base.html'%}
{%block title%}2FA{%endblock%}
{%block content%}
{% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% if messages %}
            {% for msg in messages %}
                <p style="color:red;">{{msg}}</p>
            {%endfor%}
        {%endif%}
{%endwith%}
<p>Please enter the OTP sent to your email below</p>
<form method="post">
    <p><input type="number" name="password1" placeholder="Enter OTP"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="submit"></p>
</form>
{%endblock%}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you are generating a new OTP each time, even when you are checking the previous one. So they will never match.

You could try setting the OTP in the session and checking against it instead. Something like:

```py
@app.route('/Authentication', methods = ['POST','GET'])
def Authentication():
    if request.method=='GET':
        OTP = email()
        session['OTP'] = OTP
        return render_template('2FA.html')
    elif request.method=='POST':
        pass1=request.form.get('password1')
        OTP = session.pop('OTP')
        if pass1==OTP:
            flash('business account login successful')
            session['compcode']=compcode
            session['uniquepass']=uniquepass
            return redirect(url_for('user'))
        else:
            flash('Incorrect Password')
            return redirect(url_for('logout'))
```

In the above, the `GET` version of the request will send the email with the OTP, store the OTP in the sesssion, and render the template. The `POST` version will get the OTP from the session and the code from the form and check they match.